# AVD crashes with "qemu-system-x86_64 killed by SIGSEGV" on Fedora

Tags: android-studio, fedora, android-virtual-device, qemu, flatpak

I am trying to run an AVD on Fedora 39 Workstation, but I am getting a crash with the following error: "qemu-system-x86_64 killed by SIGSEGV".
I have installed Android Studio from Flatpak.

**Expected behavior:**

The AVD should start and run without any errors.

**Actual behavior:**

The AVD crashes with the error message above.

Comment: Do you have the most recent flatpak? What is the full error message? Do you launch the emulator from the GUI or the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Fedora's **SE Linux AVC denials**.
Install SE Linux Troubleshoot GUI if not already installed: `sudo dnf install setroubleshoot`

Open its GUI and try booting up AVD from android studio. The [GUI will show the denial](https://imgur.com/a/7P9xdRP) (in my case) as *'MainThreadLoop' trying to access execheap*. Generate the local policy rule it suggests as sudo and it will work the next launch!

You may have encountered this execheap denial even in VSCode on Fedora.